# Как устранить зависание?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Почему-то при выполнении зависает и не перестаёт (а ведь по теории не должен). Как исправить зависание и добиться того, чтобы тело while выполнялось, становилась пауза 1 ms, и так много-много раз, согласно условию while'а?..

Код:

```
function razvorot(num) {
    var w = 50;
    var w2 = 50;
    var o = 1;
    if (num = 1) {
        while (w < 100) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                w++;
                w2--;
                o -= 0.02;
                document.getElementById('kortush').style.width = w + '%';
                document.getElementById('kandi').style.width = w2 + '%';
                document.getElementById('i2').style.opacity = o;
                console.log('mod1:w = ' + w + '; w2 = ' + w2);
            }, 1)
        }
        document.getElementById('i1').style.width = 'auto';
        document.getElementById('i1').style.height = '80%';
        document.getElementById('i1').style.left = '35%';
        document.getElementById('i1').onmouseover = '';
        document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        while (w < 100) {
            w++;
            w2--;
            document.getElementById('kandi').style.width = w + '%';
            document.getElementById('kortush').style.width = w2 + '%';
            console.log('mod2:w = ' + w + '; w2 = ' + w2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: офигенное условие:

    if(num = 1) {

да и вообще ваш код меня поражает, почитайте про совмествное использование циклов и setTimeout, узнайте, что такое замыкания и как они работают

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зависает только потому, что у вас идет цикл while, а вы, по всей видимости, хотите добиться анимации. Так знайте, что для этого используют setInterval, а в джквери вообще вдобавок супер-пупер навороты.

Вот как-то так:

```
   function razvorot(num) {
    var w = 50;
    var w2 = 50;
    var o = 1;
    if (num == 1) {
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            w++;
            w2--;
            o -= 0.02;
            document.getElementById('kortush').style.width = w + '%';
            document.getElementById('kandi').style.width = w2 + '%';
            document.getElementById('i2').style.opacity = o;
            console.log('mod1:w = ' + w + '; w2 = ' + w2);

            if(w > 100) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 78)
        document.getElementById('i1').style.width = 'auto';
        document.getElementById('i1').style.height = '80%';
        document.getElementById('i1').style.left = '35%';
        document.getElementById('i1').onmouseover = '';
        document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        var interval2 = setInterval(function () {

            w++;
            w2--;
            document.getElementById('kandi').style.width = w + '%';
            document.getElementById('kortush').style.width = w2 + '%';
            console.log('mod2:w = ' + w + '; w2 = ' + w2);

            if(w > 100) {
                clearInterval(interval2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код мб и не рабочий, но принцип явно видно.